# why boost::bind with deleted object is working?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, boost-asio

Look at this code :

```
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class acceptor
{
private:
    asio::ip::tcp::acceptor * a;
    asio::io_service &_service;
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep;
public:
    acceptor(asio::io_service &service, unsigned int port)
        :_service(service), ep(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)
    {
        try {
            a = new asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(service, ep);
        }
        catch (asio::system_error &e) {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
        }
        continueAccept();
    }

    ~acceptor() {
        delete a;
        cout << " destroy " << endl;
    }

    void continueAccept() {
        cout << "start accepting ..." << endl;
        boost::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> ptr(new asio::ip::tcp::socket(_service));
        a->async_accept(*ptr, boost::bind(&acceptor::handleAccept, this, ptr, asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handleAccept(
        boost::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> &socket,
        const asio::error_code &e)
    {
        if (e == asio::error::operation_aborted) {
            cout << "handler is called by error_code : " << e.message() << endl;
        }
    }

    void close() {
        cout << "close is called ..." << endl;
        a->close();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    asio::io_service service;
    acceptor *aa = new acceptor(service, 8899);

    service.poll();
    service.reset();

    delete aa;

    service.poll();
    service.reset();

    return 0;
}
```

the output is :

- start accpting ...
- destory
- handler is called by error_code : operation Aborted

when I delete the aa object in main method, the asio::ip::tcp::acceptor on destructor of aa object call his close and the asynchronous operation will call with asio::error::operation_aborted.

Now, after delete, call a method like acceptHandler on aa deleted object can't cause a **crash** or bad use memory, but is expected. Of course, I test the program with valgrind memory analyzer for possible error, but no error exists.

Question: why the program works currectly while calling a function on deleted object by boost?

Comment: Maybe not one specific to boost, but don't we already have a lot of "I can still use deleted objects" questions?

Comment: It's clear that your option for my question is 'no'.

Answer (score 5):

> why the program works currectly while calling a function on deleted object by boost?

Because that's one of the ways an undefined behaviour works. Once you delete an object, you shouldn't access it. If you do, you invoke an UB.

You were unlucky, because your program seems to work.

Comment: No, I mention that I analyze the program with valgrind software and there no using an uninitialized memory. ( maybe you know how it valgrind work: it reimplementing malloc and free on his self and detect memory leak and use uninitialize memory).

Answer (score 4):

Calling a member function via an invalid pointer gives undefined behaviour.

In this case, nothing actually dereferences that pointer, since `handleAccept` isn't virtual, and doesn't access any member variables, so the undefined behaviour of the code generated by your particular compiler happens to match what would happen if the pointer were still valid. This is unfortunate, as it makes the error harder to find.

One possibility, illustrated in some of the Asio examples such as [this one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html#boost_asio.tutorial.tutdaytime3.the_tcp_connection_class), is to manage the `acceptor` class with shared pointers; by inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this<acceptor>`, you can bind the accept function to a shared pointer, not the raw `this` pointer:

```
a->async_accept(*ptr, 
    boost::bind(&acceptor::handleAccept, 
                shared_from_this(),                 // <--- not "this"
                ptr, asio::placeholders::error));
```

Then the object will remain alive until `handleAccept` completes; and longer if that binds `shared_from_this()` to further asynchronous operations.

Comment: It's exactly correct, Therefore I can use Asio in this manner, because It can not be a UB.

Comment: @softghost: I've added a suggestion to fix the problem; your approach will work with a few small changes.

Comment: Could you point me to which section of the ISO C standard marks this as an undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Using deleted memory is considered **undefined behavior**.

You might get a crash, as you were expecting, but you can't count on anything in particular happening.